# AWS athena (presto SQL): How to take the (set-like) union of arrays in a group by statement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to combine arrays of unique userids into one single array of unique userids. AWS athena does not have the `set_union` function, so I cannot use

```
, set_union(userids)
```

And reduce_agg seems to not allow for arrays

```
, reduce_agg(userids, ARRAY[], (a, b) -> array_union(a, b), (a, b) -> array_union(a, b))
```

Is there any other trick I can use to combine arrays into one array (distinct items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `array_agg` and process the resulting array of arrays via `flatten` and `array_distinct`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, userids) AS (
    VALUES (1, array [ 1, 2, 3 ]),
        (1, array [ 3, 4, 5 ])
) 

--query
SELECT array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(userids)))
FROM dataset
GROUP BY id
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |

Comment: This works great, unfortunately until you hit the 32MB mem size limit per row

Comment: @FilippoVitale if this happens during some intermediate part of processing then you should be able to workaround with `unnest`. If the final array is too big - then I don't have an idea what can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GuruStron. What I normally do to overcome that error is with a "poor man bucketing" of that array, partitioning it in multiple arrays, easily group-able later in the query.